# Why does my buildx dockerbuild for arm takes that long?

Tags: python, docker, pip

my dockerbuild with the following command:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -t jupyterlab:3.7.12_history --load .
```

takes very long.

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.12-slim-buster

WORKDIR /

COPY wheels/scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl ./wheels/scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl

## INSTALL WITH APK
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    libjpeg-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    make \
    wget \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libffi-dev 

## INSTALL WITH PIP
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir pillow && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir pandas && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir setuptools && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir cffi && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir GLIBC && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir numpy && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir /wheels/scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir jupyterlab

.........
```

I also did one build with seperate RUN commands to see which package takes that much time.

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -t jupyterlab:3.7.12_history --load .
[+] Building 10107.8s (24/24) FINISHED                                                               
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                            0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.78kB                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring context: 218B                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7.12-slim-buster                    2.0s
 => [ 1/10] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7.12-slim-buster@sha256:e48e2fb620ea5e7cfb36bc898e  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.7.12-slim-buster@sha256:e48e2fb620ea5e7cfb36bc898ebd  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                               6.9s
 => => transferring context: 319.00MB                                                           6.9s
 => CACHED [ 2/19] COPY wheels/scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl ./wheels/scipy-1.7.3-cp  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/19] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     g++     gcc     libjpeg-dev     0.0s
 => [ 4/19] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip                                       24.2s
 => [ 5/19] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pillow                                             210.9s
 => [ 6/19] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib                                        3485.9s
 => [ 7/19] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pandas                                            5373.7s 
 => [ 8/19] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir setuptools                                           6.2s 
 => [ 9/19] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir cffi                                                40.3s 
 => [10/19] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir GLIBC                                                5.1s 
 => [11/19] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir numpy                                                4.4s 
 => [12/19] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir /wheels/scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl     20.8s 
 => [13/19] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir jupyterlab                                         884.4s
```

Here you can see that pandas and matplotlib take a very long time, to build their whl files.

**Can I shorten this process?** I am aware of caching and multistage builds.

**Is it normal that it takes several hours for these two packages?**

Thanks for your time and merry Christmas to you.

Comment: I assume you are running Docker on x86_64 which means buildx is using emulation for armv7 which is going to be very slow.  If using python3-pandas .deb is suitable, it will be much faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Before I used only the ready build whls, but there where some conflicts and others told me it is not good practice.